# Inserting data using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql

I am trying to use the following syntax to insert information into a database:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Catalog] ([CatalogID], [CatalogName], [CatalogLastUpdated], [CatalogMediaType], [CatalogComment]) 
VALUES (0, N'Important Info', CAST(0x00009F9700FC30F0 AS DateTime), N'Folder', N'lsafjalsdkf')
```

But I get the following error:

> Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Catalog' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong,..

Answer (score 1):

Don't specify a value for the IDs. Let the database generate values for you:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Catalog] ([CatalogName], [CatalogLastUpdated], [CatalogMediaType], [CatalogComment]) VALUES (N'Important Info', CAST(0x00009F9700FC30F0 AS DateTime), N'Folder', N'lsafjalsdkf')
```

Alternatively you can enable identity insert:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Catalog] ON

-- your INSERT statements here

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Catalog] OFF
```